# Machine learning and feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, artificial-intelligence

I developed my algorithm, Hybrid SVM algorithm, and correlation-based feature selection (for network intrusion detection), I have a suspicion that If I want to compare performance with other methods such as neural network or naive bayes, I have to correlate-based feature selection for neural networks and naive bayes or not? I don't have a focus on feature selection but focus on Hybrid SVM.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, you could compare feature selected SVM to non-feature selected naïve Bayes if you wanted to, I would just say the comparison wouldn't be truly fair to the naïve Bayes classifier.  Same way you could decide to tune on of your algorithms but not another.  It's probably not a great idea as you will be losing out on potentially better algorithms but you certainly could do it.  You have to weight the cost/benefit computational time/effort vs. results.

Comment: Thank you so much